# Why is the value that is always returned from the functio null or undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Whenever I run the following code the values that are returned from checkIfUserHasMadeBet() function always comes out null. It seems that the code isn't waiting for the function to return a value but rather skipping ahead. How do I make it wait for the function to return the data from the firebase database?

```
export class DisplayBetPage {
    hasCurrentUserMadeAbet: boolean = false;

    constructor(private navParams: NavParams, public navCtrl: NavController, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    }

   ionViewWillLoad() {
      var temp = this.checkIfUserHasMadeBet();
      console.log(temp); // comes out as null
      if (temp != null) {
         this.hasCurrentUserMadeAbet = true;
      }
   }

   checkIfUserHasMadeBet() {
       this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {    
           this.afDatabase.database
          .ref(`userprofile/${auth.uid}/bets/${this.bettingKey}`)
          .once(`value`).then(function(snapshot) {
                 console.log(snapshot.val()); 
                 // comes out with correct value [not null]
                return snapshot.val();
          });
       });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`var temp = this.checkIfUserHasMadeBet();` is a async call and the `console.log(temp);` which you are doing is in a synchronous context so immediately after that call the value is not resolved and is null .

**UPDATE**

There are a few things that are wrong the way are trying to achieve this first and foremost it is better to have a service to have this kind of operations rather than having it in the component itself.

The component will call the service method which will save the snapshot value in a `subject` or `behaviour subject` of the service ,then your component will  subscribe to that service observable get the value of snapshot in the subscribe and perform all the necessary operations.

Take a look @ this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) - Instead of Using Observables use either a Behaviour Subject or a Replay Subject for Passing Data between Components (Shared Services).

Follow this approach for the values to be passed to the same component the above link is like a gist for you to follow not the actual answer. In your scenario there will no observing or updating component both these components are one.

Comment: There are also nested asyncronous calls inside the observable, which makes is difficult to work with. I suggest the OP to read up on RxJS an the power of its operators in order to use them without troubles.

Comment: Okay, great thanks so how do I make it async so it waits for the call to finish?

Comment: @AdamGoldberg updated a blue print of how you can get the value